# Wait for an element to no longer be disabled in nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, element, nightwatch.js

I'm running my nightwatchjs test script against drop-down menu options, for a car **make** and **model**.

Before I select a car make, the model element is correctly disabled, and looks like the following;

[image]

When I select a make, the model element becomes enabled, and the disabled part is removed.

However, what I'd like to do is a form of wait, so that the rest of the script will wait until the element is enabled before proceeding.

At present, I have the following code;

```
browser.expect.element('#bfsDesktopFilters #ddl-model').to.be.enabled;
```

Which works for the majority of the time, but sometimes there is a slight delay in loading the model drop-down, and the test fails.

Is there a way to do this (I really don't want to use a pause)?

I've tried;

```
waitForElementToBeEnabled
waitForElementToBeClickable
```

but with no luck.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use the `getAttribute` function which would take 3 arguments; element, attribute, callback.  Pass in a res var in the callback and use the res value to get its state.  Also, not sure why you're having to use 2 #id locators, 1 should suffice.  Something like this:

```
driver.getAttribute('#bfsDesktopFilters', 'disabled', function(res) {
   // check res.value here and do something
})
```